# Toshiba (Win7 natively) won't boot from USB

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb, bios

This morning a laptop that I have suddenly turn off and, when I try to turn on again, I see the blink white dask. I suppose that MBR of my laptop is now damaged so I've tried to download a usb-bootable version of Gparted 2 (really I've tried also with other tools but without success).

I use .iso file with "TuxBox" (for make USB bootable) and tried to boot from USB (by bios priority, by pressing f12m and so on)

My pc won't start from usb

Some useful info:

- Bios version is 1.40
- I can't turn off/on secure boot as menu item isn't there
- I can't change to csm boot as menu item isn't there

#### Moreover

If i press F8 I can't access recovery partition. I'm sure that, if the partition where there, it still be there as I've never formatted this pc

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by this? "I  burnt .iso file and tried to boot from usb".              Burning and ISO is the act of burning the contents of a file onto an optical disc. You can't burn an ISO to a USB flash drive or external hard drive. You can however, copy the extracted contents of an ISO and place them on the root of your USB drive and mark it as bootable. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Geruta: Yes. You're right. I used "TuxBox" to copy files and make the USB bootable. Onto another laptop, of course, the USB is bootable and I'm able to use GParted (or every other program)

Comment: What about booting from CD/DVD ?

Comment: Didn't tryed but reading on the net it seems that will fail aswell. However I was busy and unable to try. I will.